# windmove keybinds are not loaded

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to use `windmove` with the default bindings and am unable to get the shift key bindings working correctly.

When I hit `Shift-<up>`, instead of selecting another window, the point moves and a region is selected.

Also, `C-h k RET Shift-<up>` simply shows `<up>`.

<sub>Using GNU Emacs 24.3.</sub>

Here is the entry from my `.emacs`.

```
(global-set-key "\e[1;2A" 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key "\e[1;2B" 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key "\e[1;2C" 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key "\e[1;2D" 'windmove-left)
```

I am using these entries, instead of `windmove-default-keybindings` since the default wasn't working when I opened a non-windowed emacs through tmux.

Comment: Simply shows what?

Comment: @Malabarba Forgot to apply code markup. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, this indicates you don't have windmove keybinds. Shift setting the mark is completely unrelated here (and it's the expected behavior). You'll need to provide a minimal example of how you're activating windmove.

Comment: @Malabarba Added more info. I guess I fell into the XY problem trap by not specifying everything :) The above code snippet was what I found elsewhere as a suggested solution for the tmux-based emacs issue. You are right. With `windmove-default-keybindings`, it does indeed work in the windowed version. It still doesn't work in tmux. However it is beginning to look like more of an inputrc issue since `C-h k` isn't getting it either.

Comment: After making your bindings, what does `C-h w windmove-down` tell you? Whatever key it says is the key that is bound to that command. Then do `C-h k` followed by hitting whatever keyboard key you think your keyboard uses to create the sequence `ESC [ 1 ; 2 B` (i.e., "\e[1;2B"). That tells you what that keyboard key (whatever it is) is really bound to, if anything.

Comment: @Drew Thanks! That helped. Also, using `C-h l` helped me figure out my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `(tty-type)` being of the xterm family, `\e[1;2A` wasn't being mapped to `S-<up>`. The bindings introduced by `windmove-default-keybindings` work in my non-windowed emacs setup after redefining this input as follows:

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])
```

This [link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-05/msg00211.html) has a description of this issue and solution.